# What are the specs for a top bar in a web application (1440px) according to Material Design?

Tags: navigation, web-app, material-design, google-materials-design, google+

I'm new to UX design. As a fun project, I'm designing a calendar web application while referring to Material Design. I can't seem to find anything about the top bar specs for web apps on the Material Design Website. What is the height of this top bar (for a 1440px screen)? Is it the same as top bar navigation on a mobile app? Looking at Google Photos seems to be around 88px...

Help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: For clarity, can you please take a screen shot to show us what top bar area you are referring to?

Comment: [MUI](https://material-ui.com/components/app-bar/) is a project that implements Material Design. Could be handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## It doesn't matter.

First of all, remember Material is a set of suggested guidelines. You don't have to follow them to the A (although it's a good idea in some cases, especially if you need to slap something fast).

However, Material is quite flexible when it comes to desktop. You can see that in [Material's site](https://material.io/components/app-bars-top#anatomy):

**Dense Desktop Example**

[image: Dense]

**Prominent Dense Desktop Example**

[image: Prominent Dense]

As you can see, height can vary and it's not *set in stone*. As long as it's reasonable and you keep padding and safe areas, you'll be fine

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you!